# Selenium - Windows Auth Box Issue

Tags: c#, selenium

This is an odd one I need some help with. We have an automation project with a windows auth box. We were passing in the user/pass in the url string but we started to notice some issues. I wanted to setup AutoIT and see if this fixed the issue we were seeing but the url we go to is an internal ip:port. When I goto the url ex. 123.34.56.78:1111 the browser (chrome) opens but then fails with:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7233/session/be85ee0483da9772b136488bed19c43b/url timed out after 180 seconds.'
```

It appears that webdriver is waiting for something to complete and I can't get to the next step.

I have tried the below but each one loads the page and then throws the error.

```
_webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
_webDriver.Url = url;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: couple things to confirm initially:

1. (obviously) make sure you can hit that url manually
2. Are you passing the url into `GoToUrl() as a URI object or a string?  I would try both if you haven't

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The browser opens and the auth box appears but the function for going to the url never completes. I can take over manually and login and it is fine. I am using a string currently.

Comment: tried uri - same result :(

Comment: Please verify, if you have updated chromedriver nuget.

Comment: How is `_webDriver` defined?

Comment: Chromedriver I have 72 but tried downgrading to 2.46. Same results. As for _webdriver - public static IWebDriver _webDriver;

Comment: Can you add the code that specifies your chromedriver/associated options and the _webdriver definition for good measure?

Comment: the chromedriver code works on several other automation frameworks so I am not really concerned about that but here it is. I am not sure if this is a chromedriver error. 73 is out but not in a nuget package yet. I can load the exe and call it direct. Then again our internal policies are so strict they may be blocking the way this is handled. sorry it was too large and had to push it all together lol

Comment: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions"); options.AddArguments("--start-maximized"); options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars"); options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors"); options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
_webDriver = new ChromeDriver(Path.Combine(GetBasePath, @"bin\debug"), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)); _wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));           _webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Small thing, but you shouldn't need

`_webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();` 

in addition to 

`options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");'

Comment: latest chrome and also tried chromedriver 73. I built out firefox with geckodriver and everything is working as expected. I am beginning to wonder if this is a selenium or chromedriver issue but if that was the case, we would probably see more posts about auth boxes failing.